# display inline auto marging

Tags: html, css

would like if someone with more experience could tell where is this margin coming from. thank you!!

[image]

Here is the css:

```
.logo-icon {
    background-image: url('../../images/logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 48px;
    width: 49px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}
.header {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFF;
    position: fixed;
}

.header a {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2D9CDB;
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
}
```

Comment: `.logo` `padding: 7px` -- have you tried setting padding to 0?

Comment: Also, if I add float left in my logo class it actually works the way I want, but I still don't understand where this margin in the box model is coming from!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yep, the margin stills there, if you look on the image i also set "margin right to 0px" and nothing happend :(

Comment: can you pelase make a [mcve]

Comment: Let's see the CSS for `div.user` and `div.header` because it's very likely in there. Your `div.logo` is display:block and not display:inline-block by default, so your results there are to be expected. Hard to tell without the rest of your code.

Comment: @PatrickMoore updated it ˆ-ˆ

Comment: If you add `display:inline-block;` to `.logo` and `.user` you should see the results you expect.

Comment: change the .header class width to auto

Comment: @PunithJain i also tried that, doesent work :(

Comment: thank you @PatrickMoore!! it was the display it was messing up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [CSS 2.2 spec for calculating widths](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth):

> 10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
>
> If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the values are said to be "over-constrained" ..., the specified value of '**margin-right**' is ignored and the **value is calculated so as to make the equality true**. ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the orange “margin”, then is not. You have no problem so far. To test it, try adding this test `span`:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <a class="logo.icon" href="#"></a> <a>Dashboard</a>
    <span>testing</span>  <!-- This -->
  </div>
</div>
```